# Creating tasks in Outlook to run automatically

Tags: vba, outlook, office-2010

I am trying to create an automatic task in Outlook 2010, but am having trouble doing so based on my lack of knowledge of Visual Basic, I believe.

I am trying to find a way that I can set perhaps a Macro in outlook to automatically create a calendar appointment when an email is recieved...

Everyday, I will recieve an automatically generated email from an automated system which includes my schedule for the following day. What I want to do is as soon as the email is received, I want Outlook to create an all-day appointment for the next day and add it to my calendar, including the excel spreadsheet (my schedule) which is attached to that same email.
Either for Outlook to strip the attachement away from the email and add it to the appointment, or for the entire email to become the appointment with the Excel sheet still attached.

I've had a browse around online, but cannot seem to find a solution for my problem.

If there is not a way to create the appointment for the next day, the date of the schedule is always included in the subject line (in the format DD/MM/YYYY) and as the email is generated automatically, all of the text in the subject and body remain the same; only the date is changed automatically per email and of course, the attachment too (however is always a spreadsheet in the format .xls).

The main reason that I am trying to do this is so that when I need to check my schedule, I can find it in my calendar, rather than having to trail through my emails to find it. This is especially more convenient when viewing from a mobile device. I know there are probably easier ways of simply finding the original email, but I'm hoping to be able to accomplish this way of working.

Currently, I do this manually by creating a new all-day appointment in my calendar each evening after I receive my schedule, then copy the excel spreadsheet from the email to the calendar appointment, add the subject line "Current Day Schedule", then save. This doesn't take particularly long, but to have it completed automatically would be amazing

Any assistance that anyone can provide would be incredible!

Best,

Answer (score -1):

Without providing too much actual code (although I can edit my response from home later), here is what I would do:

1. Using Outlook's NewMail event, check the subject of the most recent message. In theory the "schedule email" is pretty standard and you can identify it based on its subject.
2. If the newest message is the schedule, then open the Appointments collection and create a new item.
3. Modify all of the properties to suit your needs, including adding an attachment.

All of this requires you have some VBA knowledge...which I'm not sure you have at your disposal or not.